# Memory leaking with gsteramer appsink (python bindings)

Tags: python, memory-leaks, gstreamer, pygobject

I am trying to build pipeline with `appsink` and it eats a lot of memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import gi


gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst


def main():
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)
    # pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('fakesrc ! fakesink')
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('fakesrc ! appsink')

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    try:
        loop.run()
    except:
        pass

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Even without setting connection the memory is constantly increasing. I tried to connect a function using `sink.connect("new-sample", handler, sink)` - it also leaks memory. Also tried to add handler to bus (read somewhere that gst might enqueue messages that were not delivered to python and keep them forever) - does not help either.

Do I need to release memory somewhere? I have found calls to `gst_object_unref` in C code, but I am not sure if I should use unref in python code.

Also, simple pipeline `'fakesrc ! fakesink'` does not leak memory.

The script is running inside Docker (not sure if this matters, I cannot test outside Docker unfortunately):

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common cmake \
    gobject-introspection libgirepository1.0-dev libcairo2-dev \
    libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools \
    python-gst-1.0
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code/src
EXPOSE 8181
CMD python main.py
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you found a working solution to this yet?

Comment: @Matthias unfortunately, I don't remember. I used gstreamer for a demo application only and I ended up with rewriting to Java. I think there are two possible explanations: first is explained in the answer by Florian Zwoch (there may be some elements that were not pulled from queue - but this does not explain why calling `gc.collect()` helped in my case), second is related to missing memory limits in docker container (I'm not sure if this is applicable in your case). How do you run your code?

Comment: I have created a mini test application in Python that does nothing else than taking a photo and then reading it wieh `new-sample`. But every time I run into this memory leak as well :(

Answer (score 3):

Appsink has a queue where it stores incoming samples. By default this size is unlimited. You can control this by the `max-buffers` and `drop` properties of appsink so it does not grow infinite.

But what you actually have to do is to actively pull these samples out of the appsink and process them - or at least just drop them.

The `new-sample` signal is a good start. If that signal is triggered a new sample has arrived and is ready to be processed. I can't recall Python specifically here but you want to call `pull_sample` method of the appsink object to take ownership of the sample from the appsink to yourself. Once you get out of scope that sample should get released properly - I guess.

EDIT: Make sure the signal is emmitted. There is an appsink property `emit-signals` which is off by default. But I usually do C stuff so I'm not sure Python does flip some switches sot it works out of the box..

Answer (score 1):

For me, the biggest issue is the `MappingInfo`.

If you've received the `Gst.Buffer` anywhere in your application and require the data:

`success, map_info = buffer.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)`

Now you can easily receive the buffer data:

`data = map_info.data`

If you forget to `buffer.unmap(map_info)`, the mappings will continue to grow without being unreferenced and your memory will fill completely within seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the very same problem, forgot to unmap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution (at least hotfix) is simple: manually call `gc.collect()`

I am not exactly sure why it is not calling (or freeing) automatically, but simple calling `gc.collect()` on each `sink` handler solves the issue. This is not super-effective to call gc on each frame and I will definitely do some research on it when I have free time.

The solution was discovered by rewritting to Java (it also eats a lot of memory), but in Java you can specify `-Xmx` which reduces amount of memory available to JVM